# Weather application, that tracks a list of the cities, macos like

Tags: software-recommendation, weather

Do you know some basic application that provides a possibility to track the weather in a few (list-like) cities? I don't need much detailed information such a humidity, wind, and so on, just pure current temperature.

I've checked the following resources:

- https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/02/weather-apps-for-ubuntu-linux
- https://itsfoss.com/display-weather-ubuntu/

However, I cannot find a way to track a list of the cities within one application screen, without changing it manually.

I'm just wondering if there any app that might have looked like a macos widget
[image: macos widget]

or just a widget/extension that might be placed in the Desktop area.

If I missed some configuration in the abovementioned application, feel free to point me, I would be really thankful :)

Comment: I've never found anything that quite works for that. As I generally have a browser window open, I've just settled for using 'Forecastfox' in the browser. So, if nobody gives you a suitable answer and you end up needing/wanting to settle, there it is. It works well enough, though it's not really what I'd prefer.

Comment: just an idea,   lynx https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/australia/adelaide  then filter, change to other cities.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446334/how-to-download-a-web-page-content-to-a-text-file-exactly-as-the-web-page-is  ................lynx -dump  "https://www.timeanddate.com/weather/australia/adelaide" > dump.txt;  cat dump.txt | grep -A3 Now .........gave me a reasonable result.

Comment: and you can throw it to a notification for a second  ..... notify-send "My name is bash and I rock da house"

Comment: more output options here, you should be able to make a window that gets updated and make a script to get the weather as above .....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035/how-to-show-a-gui-message-box-from-a-bash-script-in-linux   ........  DIY Rulez when all else has failed.